# Регулярное выражение, если есть символ - исключить вхождение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не знаю как правильно описать суть вопроса, попробую показать на примере

Есть условная строка, которая содержит селекторы и стили CSS:

```
.class_3_name.class_4_name{background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0px6px12pxrgba(47,43,99,0.16);border-radius:10px;color:rgba(51,51,51,0.8);}.class_5_name{background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0px6px12pxrgba(47,43,99,0.16);border-radius:10px;color:rgba(51,51,51,0.8);}
```

Я пытаюсь найти все вхождения на селекторы следующим выражением:

```
/[.][A-z0-9)]{0,}/
```

и получаю следующие вхождения
`.class_3_name.class_4_name`, `.16`, `.8`, `.3`, `.class_5_name`, `.16`, `.8`

`.16`, `.8`, `.3` - это уже значения свойств, и после идет символ `)` либо `;`.

Каким образом можно сделать, что если следующий символ `)` либо `;`, то исключить вхождение?

В итоге хочу получить результат в виде: `.class_3_name.class_4_name` `.class_5_name`.

Либо же `.class_3_name.class_4_name{` `.class_5_name{`если это упростит задачу.

[Ссылка на онлайн пример](https://regex101.com/r/YZa7NA/2)

Comment: https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь, это тот самый случай, когда регулярное выражение сколько-нибудь разумной длины не справится, поскольку CSS — не регулярный язык. Так как Вы используете PHP, можно прибегнуть к средствам этого языка. Смысл в том, что CSS разрезается на части по набору свойств CSS, заключённому в `{}`:

```php
<?php
$css = <<<'EOT'
.class_3_name.class_4_name{background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0px6px12pxrgba(47,43,99,0.16);border-radius:10px;color:rgba(51,51,51,0.8);}
.class_5_name, .class_6_name{background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0px6px12pxrgba(47,43,99,0.16);border-radius:10px;color:rgba(51,51,51,0.8);}
EOT;

$selectors = [];
foreach (preg_split ('/\{[^}]*}/s', $css) as $group) {
    foreach (explode (',', $group) as $selector) {
        $selector = trim ($selector);
        if ($selector) {
            $selectors [] = $selector;
        }
    }
}

echo (var_export ($selectors, true));
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dabbe5a435c57d3d0277408bbb5ee85177f1740b

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы исключить из совпадений `.16`, `.8` и `.3`, нужно использовать границу слова (чтобы проверка в блоке предварительного просмотра вперёд осуществлялась только один раз после найденного слова) и блок предварительного просмотра вперёд:

```
preg_match_all('~\.\w+\b(?![);])~', $text, $matches)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ljjZDa/1).

- `\.` - точка
- `\w+` - один и более "словных" (буквоцифровых) символов (включая символ `_`)
- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?![);])` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции стоит `)` или `;`.

Эквивалентное выражение

```
\.\w+(?![\w);])
```

См. [пример работы этого регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ljjZDa/2). Тут `\w` в блоке предварительного просмотра выполняет роль границы слова.